# Laravel Database connection Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No route to host

Tags: php, laravel

I have this weird issue happened to me when I was setting up my Laravel application on live server, it gives me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No route to host
```

everything is correct though because I tested it using plain PHP PDO connection code and it's working fine but still Laravel gives me the above error, any idea how to solve this issue.

Comment: upload your `.env` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you put incorrect database host in .env file.